# maven build files, default directories

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml

I have a maven pom.xml file. I run command

```
clean package jboss-as:deploy
```

and it works fine. How is maven determining which files to include when no directories are declared within the pom.xml? Does maven default to {current_directory}/src? And where is this documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven expects your project to use a standard directory layout, described in the documentation [**here**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

[**From the docs**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html): `Having a common directory layout would allow for users familiar with one Maven project to immediately feel at home in another Maven project. The advantages are analogous to adopting a site-wide look-and-feel.`